# What command do i need to pass in SabreCommandLLSRQ to get current price of PNR?

Tags: xml, vb.net, wsdl, sabre

This is my current Request.

```
<SabreCommandLLSRQ
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<Request Output="SCREEN" CDATA="true"
    xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2003/07">
    <HostCommand>**W1</HostCommand>
</Request>
```

This is The response I am getting.

```
<SabreCommandLLSRS
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<Response
    xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2003/07">NO TKT REC EXISTS-0016
</Response>
```

I need to know what command should i Pass in this TAG for SABRE, inorder to check the current price of an existing booked PNR.

```
    <HostCommand>**W1</HostCommand>
```

> **W1 is the command used for the same in ABACUS.

somebody please let me know how to the same for sabre.
or any other service that provide result for the same.

Comment: Are you wanting to price the current PNR, or looking to read a Stored Price Quote(*PQ)

Comment: Yes i want to price current PNR, I have already used **TravelItineraryReadRQ**  to get the PNR info, Now what i need to Price the PNR, but before Pricing I want to check the current price for this PNR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command to store the price is actually PQ (if you are using SabreCommand service). Or even WPRQ can be used to price and store the price in the same command.

If you use `OTA_AirPriceLLSRQ` service, you can use the Retain flag, this way, in your request:

```
<OTA_AirPriceRQ>
....
<PriceRequestInformation Retain="true">
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Yes i had implemented it using store price as true

Answer (score 4):

If you are just looking to price the current itinerary, the Sabre commands are:

**WP** (price current itinerary with the current classes of service)

**WPNC** (price current itinerary with the lowest available fare)

**WPNCB** (price current itinerary with the lowest available fare AND rebook new classes of service, if applicable)

If all you want is the simple price of the current itin in the current classes of service, WP should give you want you want.

To my knowledge there is no API built to do that, so I think you are on the right track using HostCommand.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the support, I have implemented it using  OTA_AirPriceLLSRQ and it works fine, but I am not sure about the store price, Could you please share the Commands for Store price after pricing.

Comment: The basic command to read the Stored Price is *PQ. This information is available on the PNR Read Web Service Get Itinerary(TravelItineraryReadRQ) https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/soap_apis/management/itinerary/Get_Itinerary

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is an API for Pricing a Trip/PNR. This is the Price Air Itinerary(OTA_AirPriceLLSRQ).

You can find information about this service below:

https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/soap_apis/air/book/Price_Air_Itinerary

Comment: HI, thanks for the response, you are right currently I have done the same using OTA_AirPriceLLSRQ, but using this can lead to some other problems while ticketing, I think this service dont store price, i am not sure how it is done. There are some commands that can be used to store price.