# Sabre Get itinerary Details from PNR

Tags: php, crm, sabre

We're planning to connect our CRM to Sebre so we can get the order details from the PNR.
What API can be used to achieve this? is there any sample code in PHP? (its something like tripcase). We need to get segments details, price, tax ..etc for specific PNR created from our PCC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TravelItineraryReadRQ (soap based service) should give you all you need:

https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/soap_apis/management/itinerary/Get_Itinerary

Comment: I've checked the link you're right but it doesn't return Tax and FareBasisCode.
We can calculate Tax using this:
https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/soap_apis/air/book/Calculate_Air_Tax_for_Itinerary
but do you have an idea how to get FareBasisCode from the PNR ?

Comment: If the fare has been previously retained in the PNR, then TravelItineraryReadRQ should return them.
See sample of latest (3.6.0) with explanation of fields at:


http://files.developer.sabre.com/doc/providerdoc/pnrservices/TravelItineraryReadRS_3.6.0_Design.xml

Comment: Also, price can be retained with the PQ Sabre command (e.g.: if a travel agent created the PNR and used that command), or - if PNR was created using a service (e.g.: EnhancedAirBook --> https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/soap_apis/air/book/orchestrated_air_booking) or priced using a service such as OTA_AirPriceRQ (see answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30866226/what-command-do-i-need-to-pass-in-sabrecommandllsrq-to-get-current-price-of-pnr/34209768#34209768)